# How do you get access to initialized variables from the main class through a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have one main class named forecast. I have the __init__ function and made variables such as self.temp_c and self.city. Within that class I have made a subclass named 'current'. However, I want the 'current' subclass to have access
to self.city from the __init__ function. So then after the user initialises his variables,(city, day, days), he can then get the information about just that city.

I have tried using super().__init__(city) but doesn't work. And also tried making current a class on its own and inheriting from the forecast class.

Here is my code:

```
class forecast:
    def __init__(self, city, day=0, days=5):
        ''' days is the amount of days you want ot forecast for and day is the
        day you want to view the forecast for. 0 would be first and last would
        be the amount set for days. Leave out day for first day '''
        self.city = city
        self.full_json = client.getForecastWeather(q=city, days=days)

        self.api_url = 'http://api.apixu.com/v1/'
        self.forecast_json = self.full_json['forecast']['forecastday']
        self.text = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['condition']['text']
        self.date = self.forecast_json[day]['date']

        self.max_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['maxtemp_c']
        self.max_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['maxtemp_f']

        self.avg_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avgtemp_c']
        self.avg_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avgtemp_f']
        self.avg_hum = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avghumidity']

        self.min_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['mintemp_c']
        self.min_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['mintemp_f']

        self.astro_info = self.forecast_json[day]['astro']
        self.sunrise = self.astro_info['sunrise']
        self.sunset = self.astro_info['sunset']
        self.moonrise = self.astro_info['moonrise']
        self.moonset = self.astro_info['moonset']
        self.uv = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['uv']
    class current:
        #Hoping for:
        self.full_json = client.getCurrentWeather(q=forecast.self.city)# Or however I access that.

        self.lat = full_json['location']['lat']
        self.lon = full_json['location']['lon']
        self.text = full_json['current']['condition']['text']
        self.temp_c = full_json['current']['temp_c']
        self.temp_f = full_json['current']['temp_f']
```

Or I could just:

```
class forecast:
    def __init__(self, city, day=0, days=5):
        ''' days is the amount of days you want ot forecast for and day is the
        day you want to view the forecast for. 0 would be first and last would
        be the amount set for days. Leave out day for first day '''
        self.city = city
        self.full_json = client.getForecastWeather(q=city, days=days)

        self.api_url = 'http://api.apixu.com/v1/'
        self.forecast_json = self.full_json['forecast']['forecastday']
        self.text = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['condition']['text']
        self.date = self.forecast_json[day]['date']

        self.max_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['maxtemp_c']
        self.max_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['maxtemp_f']

        self.avg_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avgtemp_c']
        self.avg_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avgtemp_f']
        self.avg_hum = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['avghumidity']

        self.min_c = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['mintemp_c']
        self.min_f = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['mintemp_f']

        self.astro_info = self.forecast_json[day]['astro']
        self.sunrise = self.astro_info['sunrise']
        self.sunset = self.astro_info['sunset']
        self.moonrise = self.astro_info['moonrise']
        self.moonset = self.astro_info['moonset']
        self.uv = self.forecast_json[day]['day']['uv']

    class current:
        def __init__(self, city):
            self.full_json = client.getCurrentWeather(q=city)

            self.lat = full_json['location']['lat']
            self.lon = full_json['location']['lon']
            self.text = full_json['current']['condition']['text']
            self.temp_c = full_json['current']['temp_c']
            self.temp_f = full_json['current']['temp_f']
```

Comment: `current` is not a subclass of `forecast`, it's just a class defined inside it. Why do you even use a class?

Comment: what is a subclass then

Comment: A subclass *uses inheritance*. You have a *nested class*, which isn't really a common thing in Python. Not sure why you'd want it here.

Comment: ok. sorry. I didn't know. No need to get angry. Your words hurt.

Comment: The [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) is a good place to start.